# google font issue with IE only

Tags: fonts, google-font-api

No idea what is going on here.  In IE only the fonts will not render properly about 50% of the time in various places on the page.  I can literally sit there and refresh the page and sometimes there will be a few places rendered wrong, other times a few are correct and other aren't, and other times everything actually shows correct - it is completely random.  On this particular page there are 4 different areas on the page which can or cannot be rendered wrong.

Every other browser I have tried works fine with no issues - firefox, chrome, safari, iphone safari

For example... wrong on the left and correctly displayed on the right.

[image: example]

I am using the following for the fonts as the first line in the first css file loaded on the page :

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kite+One|Open+Sans:400italic,400,700);
```

What I have tried other than the above with the same results :

- loading the font files locally from my server instead of via Google
- using `<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kite+One|Open+Sans:400italic,400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>` as the first css file on each page instead of import
- loading with the Google js api

I tried searching and while I found tons of issues with Google Fonts nothing similar to this problem.  Anyone else experience this or have any ideas?

Comment: The problem appears in all IE versions?

Comment: I assume so since I am using IE 11... the easiest way to replicate is to clear all history, close browser, open and go to the site. I can't really use dev tools to test the other versions in this manner.

Comment: Actually it displays 'correct' in 7 and 8 aside from the font not looking as nice as it does in the other versions.  9,10,11 are the ones where I can refresh over and over and replicate the error.